# Inner quotes exe()

Tags: python, bash, command, exe, inline

Please, can someone help me with this silly string/command. The quotes between quotes keeps giving an error. Seriously, I have been hours try to get right the gooddamn quotes xd.

```
python3 -c "exec('import glob;things=glob.glob('/*');with open('test_output.txt', 'w') as f:  f.write('\n'.join(things))')"
```

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to escape the inner quotes like so:

```
python3 -c "exec('import glob;things=glob.glob(\'/*\');with open(\'test_output.txt\', \'w\') as f:  f.write(\'\n\'.join(things))')"
```

I changed the escaped quotes, since I don't have the files, I can't properly test it, but it is now able to process the command and attempt to run it in python.

Comment: Still gives some error: 

`code`
File "<string>", line 1
    exec(\'import glob;things=glob.glob(\'/*\');with open(\'test_output.txt\', \'w\') as f:  f.write(\'\n\'.join(things))\')
                                                                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that I am using linux bash, I haven't tried in windows.

Comment: I was still having an error, but I change the 'with open()' and the '\n'.join() and now it works scaping the quotes as you said. Should be enough, thank you!

`code` 
python -c "exec('import glob;things=glob.glob(\'/*\');f=open(\'test_output.txt\', \'w\');f.write(\'xxx\'.join(things))')"